# Refresh Datagrid Columnheader when Binding source changes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a datagrid bound to a datatable. 
Especially the column header background is bound to a row in the datagrid. This works perfectly when the datagrid is loaded, but fails when the user changes the content of the row.
How can I refresh the header?

The Datagrid colum

When a Columnheader is clicked, a method is called which modifies the contents of the datagrid.

```
public void ColumnHeaderSelected(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
        {
             datatable.rows[0][0] = "another color";
         }
// some logic needed to refresh the header
     }
```

Comment: You need to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the property that the grid is bound to (raise `PropertyChanged` with the property name), otherwise the binding doesn't get a notification that a UI update is needed. You can also inherit from `PropertyChangedBase` (part of CM) and call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PropertyName)` as it makes life easier (refactor friendly) and also marshals to the UI thread for you

Comment: Hello @Charleh, I tried that and most of the Grid is refreshed, but not the Column Header.
I am forcing a complete rebuild of the Datagrid by setting the property to null and then restore the Datatable. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Maybe the column header doesn't support property change updates - is this just standard windows datagrid?

Comment: @Carleh: This is the standard WPF datagrid. I think you nailed it - sad but true ;)